# Calculate the area of a figure

Tags: definite-integrals, area, polar-coordinates

I need to calculate the area of a figure that is bounded by lines

$$\rho=\cos(\varphi),\quad \rho=\sqrt{2}\cos(\varphi-\pi/4),\quad (-\pi/4 ≤ \varphi ≤ \pi/2)$$

Initially, I assumed that the first function is greater than the second and subtracted their squares with given boundaries. But then I set the bound from 0 to 1. I got confused about the boundary of my integral and function. Could you give me a lead?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Take a look to the lines given here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fdqja6xw6w?lang=it